# How to change kerberos passwords in Java

Tags: java, kerberos, change-password

I have to admin kerberos users directly in Java (J2EE web-app).
How can I do the equivalent to kpasswd (or kadmin) command with/without extra lib?
I found a few commercial APIs but they are very expensive...

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4):

The Kerberos Change Password protocol has been implemented in ApacheDS http://directory.apache.org/.

« Besides LDAP it supports Kerberos 5 and the Change Password Protocol. »

It's in Java, Open Source and Free as in beer.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just invoke kpasswd from your application?

```
String cmd = "kpasswd -principal foo -passwd bar";
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec(cmd);
pr.waitFor();
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
String line = "";
while ((line=r.readLine()) != null) {
  // TODO process response
}
r.close();
```

Comment: yeah it's a typo. Runtime is just a way to execute a command from Java, so if you want to change a password you can just invoke the appropriate command & arguments and if necessary process any response in the output.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll chose your solution when I am sure there is no other way, since invoking "kpasswd" from my app leads to a tricky process like
"invoke kpasswd principal" then "enter old passwd" then "enter new passwd" then "confirm new passwd" which is not very nice in Java

Comment: The other problem is the fact that a user must be able to change the passwd of an other user, like an admin. However, the "kpasswd" command asks for the old user's passwd, unknown by the admin!

Answer (score 0):

Using ApacheDS - Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>kerberos-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-M21</version>
</dependency>
```

Java:

```
KdcConfig config = KdcConfig.getDefaultConfig();
config.setHostName("ldap.server.cz");
config.setUseUdp(false);

Set<EncryptionType> enct = new HashSet<EncryptionType>();
enct.add(EncryptionType.AES256_CTS_HMAC_SHA1_96);
config.setEncryptionTypes(enct);

KdcConnection conn = new KdcConnection(config);
ChangePasswordResult res = conn.changePassword(userPrincipal, userPassword, "NewPassword");
if (res.getCode().compareTo(ChangePasswordResultCode.KRB5_KPASSWD_SUCCESS) == 0) {
    System.out.println("Password was changed!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Password change error - " + res.getCode().name());
}
```

You have to allow port 464 (tcp or udp, depends on what protocol you use).

Problem is that this returns me KRB5_KPASSWD_MALFORMED all the time :(
Error codes description - https://www.ietf.org/proceedings/50/I-D/cat-kerberos-set-passwd-04.txt .